# Hash 8-byte often ascending pointers to unique 8-byte integers in effectively random order?

Tags: c, hash

A little background first, I am trying to store a bunch of pointers in a data structure and I want to look up values.  I don't care about in-order access.  I would like to store the structures in a tree for lookup purposes, however malloc has a tendency to yield sequential addresses which would lead to pathological behavior of a simple tree.  I know I could store the pointers in some sort of self balancing tree but I don't have a library to implement that for me.  Vanilla C here.  So what I would like to do is to mix the bits of the pointer that I'd like to store so I can implement a simple tree and avoid the pathological case.

I need something that will well mix the bits since the upper-most bits will likely all be the same and the lower most bits will often be page aligned so the bottom bits will often be null.

Any good schemes that would yield decent mixing without a whole bunch of overhead?

Comment: Do you really want to hash an 8-byte value to an 8-byte value, as your title says? Or do you want to hash a pointer to an 8-bit value?

Comment: @EricPostpischil with your comment I just found that I misinterpreted the title as "Hash/Mix 8 byte value to an 8 _bit_ value"...

Comment: @EricPostpischil No, I really meant mix the bits of an 8 byte value yielding a guaranteed unique 8 byte value, hence the addition of the term Mix in my title.  I included the term hash because I hashing is a similar process and probably more familiar.  I want to take a unique value and permute it such that my sequence of ascending pointer values loses the property of ascending.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying by a large odd value may suffice: `(uintptr_t) ptr * 0xcba9876543210fed`. The images of unique input values are unique, by the [Sun Tzu Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

I invite others to comment on the choice of multiplier and on alternatives.